# Using bitmap string to store mapping between 2 entities

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 2 tables **Practitioner** and **Classification**. In **Practitioner** table I have a column name **class_bitmap** that contains a bitmap string (a string contains only **'0'** or **'1'** characters) with max length is 2000. This string represents for all classifications

**for example**: if a practitioner has classes 20 and 44 then character at 20th and 44th will be set to **'1'** and the others are still be **'0'**.

```
id pid    … class_bitmap
1  PI7923 …  01101010
2  PI9428 …  00000100
3  PI6646 …  01010101
```

Because the number of classifications now is 2000 so I hard code the string 
length to 2000 and **at initial all characters are default '0'**. If any classification id is assigned to practitioner then the character at that position (based on the id of that classification **class_id**) is set to **'1'**.

I don't know if this design is good, if in the future the classification extends to more than 2000 then this design still good? Could anyone give me some advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad design, akin to storing comma separated values as a field. How would you easily determine who is registered for class 20?

You should create a link/join table between 'practitioners' and 'classes': one record for every class that a practitioner is registered for.